# Susy - sass, not SCSS

Tags: susy-sass

I'm trying to get started with Susy (grid system) using sass and gulp. I've got the files imported but I can only find SCSS files of Susy. Are there anywhere you can get sass versions of Susy instead?

Håkan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no Susy files using the white-space Sass syntax, but that doesn't mean you have to use Scss in your code. If you import the files, Susy's mixins and functions will work in the Sass syntax exactly the way you'd expect.

```
@import susy

.example
  +span(3) // mixin
  margin-left: span(2 wide) // function
```